# SharePoint search not showing any results when searching partial name such as "frank"

Tags: 2013, search, search-results

I have search service application configured.

Suppose my first name is "frankmartin" (no spaces)

When I search "frankmartin" then it displays search results in both "People" and "Site" search. But when I search "frank" it doesn't display any search result. Why is that?

**EDIT**

I am not using advanced search and have made this search results page using those search web parts which you can add in page to display results.

Comment: You can also get SharePoint to automatically include a * wildcard in the search. Try this tutorial - http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2013/08/enable-wildcard-search-by-default-in-sharepoint.html Thanks
Joel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how the search in SharePoint works, if you want to include partial matches you need to use prefix matching, that is adding a * at the end of your word like

```
Frank*
```

Note that SharePoint does NOT support suffix matching, like

```
*martin
```

This will not work as expected

Answer (score 2):

Also, SharePoint supports both nickname matching (search "Bob" and get "Robert", search "Hank" and get "Henry") and phonetic matching (search "Low" and get "Lo", "Lowe", etc.). Neither of these patterns support the search you are attempting, so I would use "Frank*"

Comment: Which is super if your are in a land where those nicknames is common. But here in Sweden for exampel, call me Bob is quite a stretch :P

Comment: You would have to investigate the multilingual nature of it. The team is from Norway, so I would assume they have you covered.