# why search results not showing while searching with the half name in sharepoint 2010

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, search

Here i configured the search services but while searching with half name of  the uploaded document the search results are not showing the document..

Answer (score 0):

This is how the search in SharePoint works, if you want to include partial matches you need to use prefix matching, that is adding a * at the end of your word like( searching United)

```
Uni*
```

Note that SharePoint does NOT support suffix matching, like

```
*Uni
```

This will not work as expected

[SharePoint search not showing any results when searching partial name such as "frank"](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84959/sharepoint-search-not-showing-any-results-when-searching-partial-name-such-as-f?rq=1)

Comment: how to search without star..

Comment: Your Answer helped me a lot but i need to search without star is there any way to do that..thanks in advance

Comment: You may try to use the keywords.http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/add-keyword-terms-with-best-bets-HA101794966.aspx

Comment: Its not working...

Comment: What you mean by not working?